# Trigger Cloud Run job by uploaded file in a Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

As event-driven Cloud Functions are limitted to 10 minutes execution, I have implemented a Cloud Run Job which better suits my needs. I can run the Cloud Run job manually and everything is fine.

Now, I would like to trigger a Cloud Run job execution by Cloud storage event ([similarly like it is possible for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)), but there seems to be a no easy way. Only way I can think of is implement a Cloud function which would listen for such event and then run the job manually.

Is there some more native way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs).  You can generate events from Cloud Storage (and many other GCP products) and arrange to receive them in Cloud Run or some other compute product.

Comment: I looked. EventArc however can trigger only regular Cloud Run services, I would like to trigger Cloud Run Job and I didn't find a way how to.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear that jobs can only be invoked directly or on some schedule.  What you're describing is neither of those.

Comment: I know. That is why I am asking if it is the only way of triggering the job via cloud function or if there is some better way.

Comment: If you look through the Eventarc docs again, you will see that a Cloud Run container can receive an event directly. That would be one less thing to write and deploy if you can keep it all in one container.  The very first link for the quickstart does exactly this.

Comment: Only thing I can see is triggering Cloud Run SERVICE and not JOB (https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/creating-triggers)

Comment: Right, but you wouldn't have to worry about Cloud Functions at all, which is a simpler way of doing this, no?

Comment: Yeah, but Cloud Run service is not Cloud Run Job and meant for a different kind of tasks, otherwise Cloud Run Jobs would have no use?

Comment: Why do you want to use Cloud Run jobs? Do you have multiple task to perform in parallel? How long take the job?

Comment: I am afraid I will not be able to use Cloud Run jobs in the end, because the task "might" take over 60 minutes to complete. But yeah – I might have up to 100 parallel tasks which might be cpu-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

The more native way you are asking for is using Storage event -> Workflow -> Run Job:

Have a look: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/execute-cloud-run-jobs#gcloud_1